# Change language for all the activities from one menu click

Tags: java, android, localization

Want to change whole application language on single select.

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static Button english,russian;
    private static TextView chooseText;
    private static Locale myLocale;

//Shared Preferences Variables
private static final String Locale_Preference = "Locale Preference";
private static final String Locale_KeyValue = "Saved Locale";
private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initViews();
    setListeners();
    loadLocale();
}

//Initiate all views
private void initViews() {
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Locale_Preference, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    chooseText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choose_text);
    english = (Button) findViewById(R.id.english);
    russian = (Button) findViewById(R.id.russian);

}

//Set Click Listener
private void setListeners() {
    english.setOnClickListener(this);
    russian.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    String lang = "en";//Default Language
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.english:
            lang = "en";
            break;
        case R.id.russian:
            lang = "ru";
            break;

    }

    changeLocale(lang);//Change Locale on selection basis
}


//Change Locale
public void changeLocale(String lang) {
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        return;
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);//Set Selected Locale
    saveLocale(lang);//Save the selected locale
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);//set new locale as default
    Configuration config = new Configuration();//get Configuration
    config.locale = myLocale;//set config locale as selected locale
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());//Update the config
    updateTexts();//Update texts according to locale
}

//Save locale method preferences
public void saveLocale(String lang) {
    editor.putString(Locale_KeyValue, lang);
    editor.commit();
}

//Get locale method in preferences
public void loadLocale() {
    String language = sharedPreferences.getString(Locale_KeyValue, "");
    changeLocale(language);
}

//Update text methods
private void updateTexts() {
    chooseText.setText(R.string.tap_text);
    english.setText(R.string.btn_en);
    russian.setText(R.string.btn_ru);

  }
}
```

I am able to change the single activity language by using above code. But I want to change all application language on a single click.Please help me for doing this.I am trying to allow language access from device setting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292013/how-can-i-change-language-of-whole-application-by-only-single-click

Comment: https://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change language of whole application by only single click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292013/how-can-i-change-language-of-whole-application-by-only-single-click)

Answer (score 1):

create a class LocalHelper.java to manage localisation of your app.

```
public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "SELECTED_LANGUAGE";

    public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }

        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        }

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context;
    }
}
```

And in your application class you need to override attachBaseContext and call LocaleHelper.onAttach() to initialize the locale settings in your application.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base, "en"));
    }
}
```

whenever a change in your language happens, you need to call

```
LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, yourNewLanguageCode);
```

This will make change in all the other activities but not the activity in which you changed your language. So you need to either recreate that activity or update the views of the activity.

For recreating activity, call

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, CurrentActivity.class))
finish();
```

And if you want to go with updating views rather than recreating activity, make use of the `context` returned from `LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, yourNewLanguageCode)`

```
Context context = LocaleHelper.setLocale(this, languageCode);
Resources resources = context.getResources();

textView.setText(resources.getString(R.string.textTitle));
```

Note: After Android API Version 24(Nougat) you need to override `attachBaseContext` in all the activity to reflect changes.

Comment: Thank you, it is helpful

Comment: I have make it +1 because your helper class is useful for me. :)